# Ошибка в сортировке массива Java

Tags: java, сортировка

Привет, пишу сортировку масcива.
Выдает ошибку тут:

```
n = arr[i];
```

Вот сам код:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        int n = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int a = 0;
        for(i = arr.length; i >= 0; i--){ // i = 4
            while(i>=0) { // i=>0
                a++; // 1, 2, 3 ,4
                for (i = i; i<=arr.length-a; i--){ // i<= 4, 3, 2 , 1, 0
                    n = arr[i]; //  n = 5
                    arr[i] = arr[i--]; // arr[4] = 4
                    arr[i--] = n; // arr[3] = 5
                }
            }
        }

        for(int s = 0; s<=arr.length; s++) {
            System.out.println(arr[s]); // 5 4 3 2 1
        }
    }
```

вот сама ошибка:

> Quote: Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5

понял что с индексом массива что-то не так. Так вроде последний элемент массива то есть в мое случае arr[4] = arr[arr.lenght], или это не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нет не так. `arr.lenght` вернет длину массива, если в массиве есть хотя бы 1 элемент, то его длинна 1 а не ноль.

Соответственно в вашем случае `arr.lenght` возвращает 5, а индексация массива от 0 до 4.

```
индекс 0, элемент # 1
индекс 1, элемент # 2
индекс 2, элемент # 3
индекс 3, элемент # 4
индекс 4, элемент # 5
максимальный индекс = 4, длина массива = 5.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в циклах
`for(i = arr.length; i >= 0; i--)` и `for(int s = 0; s<=arr.length; s++)` из-за размерности массива. arr.length - длинна массива, а нумерация в массиве начинается с 0. Правильный код: `for(i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)` и `for(int s = 0; s < arr.length; s++)`